# if else statements returning else value even when they should return if value?

Tags: java

Thanks for any help in advance. Please note I am a beginner. Below is the code. It only prints the else statements value being "Thank you for buying with us" even when the if statements value should be getting printed to the console instead?

```
class Main {
  
String type;
double price;
boolean order;

public Main(String whatPizza, double costOfPizza, boolean yourOrder){
  if (price > 10.00){
    System.out.println("Thank you for spending over 10 pounds with us!");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Thank you for buying with us!");
  }

  type = whatPizza;
  price = costOfPizza;
  order = yourOrder;
}


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //empty for now
  Main personA = new Main("Pepperoni", 11.00, true);
  Main personB = new Main("Cheese", 9.00, true);

    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to set the values before the if-statement. Otherwise price still has its default value of zero.

Comment: price > 10.00 should be corrected to costOfPizza > 10.00. (price is defaulted to 0)

Comment: The underlying problem is that you should _not_ have that kind of logic in your constructor so the if/else and the printing should be in a separate method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your code is not right. You don't have any value assigned to price when you run the if-statement. Right now the double variable price is always empty, so it's never bigger than 10.00, thus being false and returning the else. This should do the trick:

```
class Main {
  
String type;
double price;
boolean order;

public Main(String whatPizza, double costOfPizza, boolean yourOrder){

  type = whatPizza;
  price = costOfPizza;
  order = yourOrder

  if (price > 10.00){
    System.out.println("Thank you for spending over 10 pounds with us!");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Thank you for buying with us!");
  }

  ;
}


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //empty for now
  Main personA = new Main("Pepperoni", 11.00, true);
  Main personB = new Main("Cheese", 9.00, true);

    }
  }
```

Comment: @benstackoverflow don't forget to mark this as the answer ;)